# TimePicker Minute Intervals

Tags: android, timepicker, dialogfragment

I have built a view with a Date Picker and a Time Picker in spinner format.  Everything seems to be working good except I can't figure out how to set the minutes to be in 5 minute intervals?

I have seen examples of how to do this using a DialogFragment and have used DialogFragments to launch separate activities with a Date Picker or a Time Picker, but I am trying to create an activity with both.

I need to either modify my current code to change the minute interval or incorporate a DialogFragment in my code that works with Time Picker that is embeded in my view.

I can't find any examples of how to do either one.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DatePicker simpleDatePicker = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.date_picker); // initiate a date picker

        //Above API 26
        // ????
        simpleDatePicker.setOnDateChangedListener(new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                // Do something
            }
        });

        TimePicker simpleTimePicker = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.time_picker); // initiate a time picker

        simpleTimePicker.setIs24HourView(true);// set to 24 hour

        simpleTimePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                // Do somthing
            }
        });
    }

    public void cancelBTN(View view) {
    }

    public void saveBTN(View view) {
    }
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancelBTN"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:background="@color/gray"
            android:onClick="cancelBTN"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:background="@color/gray"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Select Date - Time"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/saveBTN"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@color/gray"
            android:onClick="saveBTN"
            android:text="Save"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <DatePicker
            android:calendarViewShown="false"
            android:datePickerMode="spinner"
            android:id="@+id/date_picker"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/saveBTN"
            />

        <TimePicker
            android:timePickerMode="spinner"
            android:id="@+id/time_picker"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/date_picker"

            />


    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

I found a way to without a DialogFragment.  I added a new function and called it after initializing the TimePicker.  Se below code for details.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DatePicker simpleDatePicker = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.date_picker); // initiate a date picker

        //Above API 26
        // ????
        simpleDatePicker.setOnDateChangedListener(new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                // Do something
            }
        });

        TimePicker simpleTimePicker = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.time_picker); // initiate a time picker

        simpleTimePicker.setIs24HourView(true);// set to 24 hour

        setTimePickerInterval(simpleTimePicker);

        simpleTimePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                // Do somthing
            }
        });
    }

    private void setTimePickerInterval(TimePicker timePicker) {
        try {
            int TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL = 5;
            NumberPicker minutePicker = (NumberPicker) timePicker.findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier(
                    "minute", "id", "android"));
            minutePicker.setMinValue(0);
            minutePicker.setMaxValue((60 / TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL) - 1);
            List<String> displayedValues = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 60; i += TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL) {
                displayedValues.add(String.format("%02d", i));
            }
            minutePicker.setDisplayedValues(displayedValues.toArray(new String[0]));
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    public void cancelBTN(View view) {
    }

    public void saveBTN(View view) {
    }
}
```

Comment: this works with android 11 as well. thanks @Simon

NumberPicker minutePicker = (NumberPicker) timePicker.findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier(
                    "minute", "id", "android"));

Answer (score 2):

Use CustomTimePickerDialog instead of TimePickerDialog. I think your problem will be solved.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class CustomTimePickerDialog extends TimePickerDialog {

    private final static int TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL = 5;
    private TimePicker mTimePicker;
    private final OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener;

    public CustomTimePickerDialog(Context context, OnTimeSetListener listener,
            int hourOfDay, int minute, boolean is24HourView) {
        super(context, TimePickerDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT, null, hourOfDay,
                minute / TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL, is24HourView);
        mTimeSetListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateTime(int hourOfDay, int minuteOfHour) {
        mTimePicker.setCurrentHour(hourOfDay);
        mTimePicker.setCurrentMinute(minuteOfHour / TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        switch (which) {
            case BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                if (mTimeSetListener != null) {
                    mTimeSetListener.onTimeSet(mTimePicker, mTimePicker.getCurrentHour(),
                            mTimePicker.getCurrentMinute() * TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL);
                }
                break;
            case BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                cancel();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        try {
            Class<?> classForid = Class.forName("com.android.internal.R$id");
            Field timePickerField = classForid.getField("timePicker");
            mTimePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(timePickerField.getInt(null));
            Field field = classForid.getField("minute");

            NumberPicker minuteSpinner = (NumberPicker) mTimePicker
                .findViewById(field.getInt(null));
            minuteSpinner.setMinValue(0);
            minuteSpinner.setMaxValue((60 / TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL) - 1);
            List<String> displayedValues = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 60; i += TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL) {
                displayedValues.add(String.format("%02d", i));
            }
            minuteSpinner.setDisplayedValues(displayedValues
                    .toArray(new String[displayedValues.size()]));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this will solve my problem.  Unfortunately I can't figure out how to initiate the TimePicker with the CustomTimePickerDialog in my main activity?

Comment: If  you target api 30 with a device running android 11, The following code throws an exception classForid.getField("minute").  You can avoid it by using instead  (NumberPicker) timePicker.findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier(
                    "minute", "id", "android"))  as @Simon did in his code.